# Facebook app permissions when fanpage is liked

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, fan-page

I had wanted to check if people like my fanpage so I had to create app on Facebook. I connected themselves on Facebook too. Below my code:

```
require_once('facebook/facebook.php');
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId' => '574707409300181',
        'secret' => 'xxxxxx',
        'cookie' => true));
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if($user) {
    try {
        $our_page_id = '263807853767281'; // This should be string
        $user_is_fan = false;
        $likes = $facebook->api( '/me/likes?fields=id' );
        foreach( $likes['data'] as $page ) {
            if( $page['id'] === $our_page_id ) {
                $user_is_fan = true;
                echo 'YOU LIKE FANPAGE!';
            }
        }
    } 
    catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        $user = null;
    }
}
```

My question - when user press "like" button on Facebook is possible to show window with the permission's accepting of my app? I'm asking because i don't know how promote my app... Maybe is there better solution? In short words - when user likes my fanpage he have to accept permissions. :)
Thank you for reply!

Comment: like gating is not possible and not allowed anymore, the user_likes permission will not get approved for this. check out the platform policy and changelog of facebook.

Comment: Any idea how get user like without permissions or how easy get permissions?

Comment: there is no way, and as i said: like gating is not allowed anymore.